# Dispatch queue from another queue in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5

`enter code here`I'm trying to dispatch queue from another queue in laravel rightnow. So for example I have created a job like this :

```
class CandidateQueue extends Job implements SelfHandling
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct($request)
    {        

        $this->request = $request;
    }

 public function handle()
 {
      ....
      $this->dispatch($queueEmail);

    }
}
```

The problem is when executing $this->dispatch(), laravel said `"Call to undefined method ....::dispatch()"`. So How do I trigger this queue from current queue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but how I did was instead of

```
$this->dipatch(new queueEmail);
```

I did

```
dispatch(new queueEmail);
```